# What is the maximum number of Locations Discovered that one can achieve in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Under Stats | General, there is a counter for Locations Discovered at the top. What is the maximum number one can achieve in this? I have tried googling the answer but I am not able to find satisfactory answer.

There are some self reports of people achieving 348, 329 or 323 in various places in internet and some obviously wrong answers like 719, but strangely enough I am not able to find definite answer for this. Is there a way to find out a definitive answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well according to the Skyrim wiki there are 719 locations. Link is [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Skyrim:_Locations)

**EDIT**

Sorry the above answer has overlapping locations:

Another link in the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Locations_%28Skyrim%29) states there are 616. This includes locations in cities as well.

**Second Edit**

Sorry I misread your question. This [link](http://www.gamebanshee.com/skyrim/mapofskyrim.php/lnull#null) is to gamshee and show all the locations just on the skyrim world map (which should all be discoverable). There is a total of 343 locations on this map.

Comment: But there are many minor locations that exist but do not get discovered. For example, houses within cities are locations, but are not discoverable. Mines attached to towns are locations but are not discoverable. Many minor locations in the wild do not count as discovered locations.

Comment: @Anderson that's not really relevant to the stat "Locations Discovered".

Comment: @kotekzot my comment was in response to the original post and first edit, where a large number of the locations listed were houses.

Comment: I am now fairly certain that number higher than 343 is possible. There is a report of 348 on here: http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/t79yp/anyone_gotten_higher_than_348/ I think it's because there are some locations that are not in the map, such as locations in Blackreach and Sovngard

Answer (score 2):

I have found 363 on xbox360. That includes all dlc including the 3 land plots you get in hearth fire.

Now I can't discover the 4 imperial camps due to the choices I made in game, but this should be actually total. I compared to an online map when I had 361 and found 2 plus 4 imperial camps that I did not have on my ingame map.

By the way, I have 367.33 hours on game so I was very thorough.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on ps3 no DLC obviously and I'm at 337
There's two more storm cloak camps I know off
Would make it 339 
I've played 200+ hours and my map is covered so 348 would be realistic

Answer (score -2):

In one of my games I found 374 map locations, I think the total number of map locations is around the 500 mark.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We try to give a little bit more broad answers than just one line. Did you find the 374 locations in a vanilla game or did you add mods or DLC? (The original answer and quetion are sadly also lacking DLC information). (apparently dawnguard adds 24 locations, do not know if these are all on the map).